# Check whether user is going towards POI or going away from POI android - Google Directions or Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I wanna check whether User is driving towards to specific POI or User is going away from POI. The scenario is as per below image :

[image]

SO how can I track the user's specific direction? Is it possible using Google Directions or Google MAPs API or any other API? Or Can we do any mathematical calculations to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you asking about any POI or a specific POI?

Comment: @Verma : Specific POI. I will have coordinates of that specific POI

Comment: Then you can use direction api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/